# Django userena error Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I am using Django Userena and in the password reset portion i am getting the following error whenever i click on the **password reset** link.I am using Django 1.6.I have found several questions about the password reset issue,nothing has come fruitful to solve my problems.

**Error**:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/password/reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not      found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://med.finder-lbs.com/accounts/password/reset/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not    found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from userena import views as userena_views
from userena import settings as userena_settings

# Reset password
url(r'^password/reset/$',
   auth_views.password_reset,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_form.html',
    'email_template_name': 'userena/emails/password_reset_message.txt',
    'extra_context': {'without_usernames': userena_settings.USERENA_WITHOUT_USERNAMES}
    },
   name='userena_password_reset'),
url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_done,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_done.html'},
   name='userena_password_reset_done'),
url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_confirm_form.html'},
   name='userena_password_reset_confirm'),

url(r'^password/reset/confirm/complete/$',
   auth_views.password_reset_complete,
   {'template_name': 'userena/password_reset_complete.html'}),
```

and this the part of the  **template** where the reverse occuring,

```
<p class="forgot-password"><a href="{% url 'userena_password_reset' %}" title="{% trans 'Forgot your password?' %}">{% trans "Forgot your password?" %}</a></p>
```

Comment: show `userena/password_reset_form.html` template?

Comment: You should avoid using wildcard imports such as ```from django.conf.urls import *```

Answer (score 3):

This is because Django's built-in password_reset function is calling `reverse('password_reset_done')`. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L142).

What you'll want to do is pass the name of the url in the argument `post_reset_redirect` that you want `password_reset` to redirect to.