# NoReverseMatch at /user/password_reset/ Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm trying to use the Django authentication system, but I'm getting the error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPn3f.png)

'user' is an app name.

Project's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     ...
     url(r'^user/', include('user.urls', namespace='user')),
     ...
]
```

user/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^settings/$', views.settings, name='settings'),
    url(r'^settings/password/$', views.password, name='password'),
    url(r'^settings/accounts/$', views.configure_accounts,
        name='configure_accounts'),
    url(r'^settings/accounts/error/$', views.configure_accounts_error,
        name='configure_accounts_error'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

I can access /user/login/, /user/logout/. When I go to /user/password_reset/, I can enter email, and, after pressing 'Submit' button, an error occurs (shown at picture):

```
NoReverseMatch at /user/password_reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: you saw that question and tried what the guys answered? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522689/django-userena-error-reverse-for-password-reset-done-with-arguments-and-k

Comment: @hansTheFranz Yeah, I tried that. But I have `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` in settings.py. And, when using that solution,  after submitting email on reset page, nothing is displayed in console. However, redirecting works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {
        'post_reset_redirect': '/user/password_reset/done/'
    }, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done,
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, {
         'post_reset_redirect': '/user/reset/done/'
    }, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete,
        name='password_reset_complete'),
```

I set 'post_reset_redirect' in user/urls.py , and everything started to work properly. And after submitting email on reset page, nothing was displayed in console, because of this:

> If the email address provided does not exist in the system, this view won’t send an email, but the user won’t receive any error message either. This prevents information leaking to potential attackers.

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue too. These posts are outdated, so I want to give a revised answer. Essentially the `PasswordResetConfirmView` has the property of `success_url` which can be set at `urls.py`.

So for example...

```
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='password-reset-confirm.html', success_url=reverse_lazy(
        'user:password_reset_complete')),
     name="password_reset_confirm"),
```

The problem is the default behavior of the Password Reset Confirm. Specifically it sets the `success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete')`. Since your `password_reset_complete` view is in your "user" app, it can't find it. The default property is telling it to look at the *root* `urls.py` when you need it to be looking at `user/urls.py`. Overriding the `success_url` will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your user/urls.py, it seems that you have no url, named `/user/password_reset/`

if you want to use django.auth default password reset then use,

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^/accounts/password/reset/$', password_reset,{'template_name': 'my_templates/password_reset.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
     ...
)
```

Here you can change your template name.

Comment: I got `ImportError: No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'` doing this.

Comment: register 'django.conf.urls.defaults' in your installed apps in settings.py

Comment: That guy [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34937436/7999403) gave another solution. But, as I said, I have EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' in settings.py. And, when using that solution, after submitting email on reset page, nothing is displayed in console. However, redirecting works.